# Login module for Flask application using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, flask

I have a Flask application (Plotly Dashboard) deployed in an AWS EC2.

I am looking for a way to create a login/register module for the flask dashboard. I have the login/register forms in pure HTML/CSS files and the backend written in PHP.

Question is, is it possible to make the PHP login/register module work with the flask app? More specifically, have the dashboard's URL restricted if the user is not logged in and accessible only after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I would recommend [JWT authentication](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) for that.

- First you create a php login system that checks for the user's credentials, and if they are right, issue a JWT
- Then You create a middleware in your Plotly Dashboard that checks if the token is valid, and if its, allow access.

It will require some study, but it is perfectly doable.

As a starting point, you can read the [difference between Session and Token Based Authentication](https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/session-vs-token-based-authentication-11a6c5ac45e4)

And as an alternative, you can use some services like [Cloudflare access](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-access/), that serves the same purpose.